# SQL query to retrieve data between two dates from two columns

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008

SQL query to retrieve data between two dates from two columns

```
select distinct mname 
from tb_reqmach  
where fromdate >= '2016/12/08' 
  and todate <= '2016/12/30' 
  and mcfact = 'BSC - 3' 
group by mname
```

When I use the above query it returns null. value from db

[The figure attached is the data saved in db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dsIci.jpg)

Please help to retrieve the rows when the from date and two date is between the saved dates

When I use

```
select distinct mname 
from tb_reqmach  
where fromdate >= '2016/12/01' 
  and todate <= '2016/12/30' 
  and mcfact = 'BSC - 3' 
group by mname
```

it retrieves rows, and when I use

```
select distinct mname, fromdate 
from tb_reqmach  
where '2016/12/08' between fromdate and todate
```

this also retrieves rows

But I need to retrieve as per my requirement

Comment: your requirement is a bit unclear. In your first query you have mentioned fromdate>= '2016/12/08' and todate<='2016/12/30' and in your screenshot and is no matching record, thats why your are getting null in result set.

Comment: Define table with current output and excepted output

Comment: Compare date you can use datediff function:datediif(d,'2016/12/08', fromdate)>=0 and datediif(d, todate,,'2016/12/30')>=0 . Actually, I think check date range, each date column point need  two dates

Comment: if fromdate is 2016-12-01 and todate is 201-12-30  is saved in db

Comment: if i select datas betweeen 2016-12-08 to 2016-12-25 it has to retrieve that datas which is saved as 2016-12-01 as fromdate and 2016-12-30 as todate

Comment: because the my selcted between date is present in between the saved date

Comment: please anyone helpp....

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
select distinct mname 
from tb_reqmach  
where fromdate >= DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, '2016/12/08'), 0)
  and todate <= DATEADD (dd, -1, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, '2016/12/25') + 1, 0)) 
  and mcfact = 'BSC - 3' 
group by mname
```

Use equal in the condition if want to retrieve only the first day and last day data from fromdate, to date respectively.

Comment: Can you add some explanation as to what your code is doing?

Comment: If we provide filter date as 2016-12-08 to 2016-12-25 then it will retrieve data from 2016-12-01 to 2016-12-31.

Answer (score 0):

sql no needs more!
use this:

```
select distinct mname 
from tb_reqmach  
where fromdate >= '2016/12/08' 
  and mcfact = 'BSC - 3' 
group by mname
```

then take a look for result:
is there any rows that (todate <= '2016/12/30') ??

the screen shot can not help in range.

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct mname 
from tb_reqmach  
where fromdate >= convert(datetime, '2016-12-08') 
  and todate <= convert(datetime, '2016-12-30') 
  and mcfact = 'BSC - 3' 
group by mname
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have not included your requirement, you have just included SQL that you think does something you want.

This SQL:

```
select distinct mname 
from tb_reqmach  
where fromdate >= '2016/12/08' 
  and todate <= '2016/12/30' 
  and mcfact = 'BSC - 3' 
group by mname
```

Will only fetch rows that have fromdate later or equal to Dec 8 **and** todate less or equal to Dec 30. There are no such rows in your screenshot.

My guess is that you're looking for something that fetches all the rows that are valid sometimes between the given date range, and this will do it:

```
select distinct mname 
from tb_reqmach  
where fromdate <= '20161230'
  and todate >= '20161208'
  and mcfact = 'BSC - 3' 
group by mname
```

This is also the date format you should be using, others are affected with regional settings.